# replace all numbers with \n+numbers+\n

Tags: bash, awk, sed, tr

I want to replace all numbers in a string with  newline+numbers+newline.

Change the string

```
1xxx2yyy3zzz
```

into

```
  1
  xxx
  2
  yyy
  3
  zzz
```

Both of them can't make the trick.

```
echo "1xxx2yyy3zzz"  |tr  '0-9'  '\n0-9\n'
echo "1xxx2yyy3zzz"  |tr  '[0-9]'  '\n[0-9]\n'
echo "1xxx2yyy3zzz"  |tr  [:digit:]    \n[:digit:]\n
```

Comment: `tr` does not do regexp, try `sed`.

Comment: Define number. Is `+3.14159e-22` a number? If you only want integers (or even only *positive* integers), you should make that clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that your Input_file is same as shown sample then following may help you.

```
sed -E 's/[a-zA-Z]+/\n&\n/g;s/\n$//' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code too now. It is only for explanation purposes only.

```
sed -E '       ##Starting sed here and -E option is for extended regex enabling it.
s              ##s is for substitution.
/[a-zA-Z]+/    ##look for regex all small of capital letter alphabets and substitute them with following regex.
\n&\n/         ##Substitute above match with a NEW line matched value and a NEW line here.
g;             ##g means perform this action to all matched patterns on current line.
s/             ##Starting a new substitution here.
\n$            ##Substituting NEW LINE which is coming in last of the line with following.
//             ##Substituting above with NULL.
' Input_file   ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: The OP didn't say that the characters that aren't numbers are letters. You should probably be using `[^0-9]` rather than `[a-zA-Z]`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if use `tr` is possible or effective for this case. But with `sed` you could try:

```
echo "1xxx2yyy3zzz"| sed 's/[0-9]/\n&\n/g'| sed '/^\s*$/d'
```

So basically it replaces every number to `\n number \n`. The last `sed` is to delete blank lines(begin and end).

**Another Form**

To just use one `sed` and if your text is in `file`:

```
sed 's/[0-9]/\n&\n/g;s/\(^\n\|\n$\)//' file
```

- The first substitution(`s/[0-9]/\n&\n/g;`) replaces any `number` to `\n number \n`.
- The second substitution(`s/\(^\n\|\n$\)//`) deletes unneccesary new lines in begin and end.

Comment: You could do this within single `sed` you could see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51580978/5866580 this then.

Comment: I see, is the inverse logic.

Comment: `/\([0-9]\)/\n\1\n/` = `/[0-9]/\n&\n/`

Comment: Thanks @Ed Morton!, I will modify it.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[[:digit:]]\+/\n&\n/g;s/^\n\|\n$//g' file
```

Surround digits by newlines and then remove any extra newlines at the start and end of the line.

Another couple of toy solutions:

```
sed -r ':a;s/(([^0-9\n])([0-9]+))|(([0-9]+)([^0-9\n]))/\2\5\n\3\6/g;ta'
```

This is interesting in that it uses *ghost* back references in the RHS of the substitution.

```
sed '/\n/!s/[[:digit:]]\+/\n&\n/g;/^\n/!P;D' file
```

This does a one-off substitution and then uses the `P` `D` combination to loop through the line chomping off sections of the string delimited by newlines.

Answer (score 0):

With python3.

```
>>> import re
>>> string="1xxx2yyy3zzz"
>>> print(re.sub('(\d+)',r'\n\1\n',string))

1
xxx
2
yyy
3
zzz
>>> print(re.sub('(\d+)',r'\n\1\n',string).strip())
1
xxx
2
yyy
3
zzz
```